# tessbaseAPI.getUTF8Text() crashes when run on Samsung GalaxyTab

Tags: android, tesseract

I am working on a OCR based *Android* app. I am using the Tesseract library for the same. My application works fine on a *Sony Ericsson Xperia Arc S* device. However, the same app crashes on my *Samsung Galaxy Tab 8.9*. I am not sure why this is happening. Following is code snippet:

```
TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI();

baseApi.init(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/tesseract/", "eng",TessBaseAPI.OEM_DEFAULT); 
baseApi.setImage(bitmap);

String recognizedText=baseApi.getUTF8Text();    //App Crashes here
```

How can it be resolved?

Unfortunately the logCat does not report any error.

Following is the output I see in the logCat:

```
02-12 09:57:20.720: I/Tesseract(native)(5577): Initialized Tesseract API with language=eng
02-12 09:57:20.720: D/dalvikvm(5577): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.project.meter_reader/lib/liblept.so 0x4074d618
02-12 09:57:20.720: D/dalvikvm(5577): Shared lib '/data/data/com.project.meter_reader/lib/liblept.so' already loaded in same CL 0x4074d618
02-12 09:57:21.030: D/dalvikvm(5577): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.project.meter_reader/lib/liblept.so 0x4074d618
02-12 09:57:21.030: D/dalvikvm(5577): Shared lib '/data/data/com.project.meter_reader/lib/liblept.so' already loaded in same CL 0x4074d618
02-12 09:57:24.160: I/dalvikvm(5577): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
02-12 09:57:24.160: I/dalvikvm(5577): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

At `baseApi.getUTF8Text()` the application displays a blank screen and simply stops responding, then the debugger gets detached.

Comment: @rmtheis: Before the app crashes the screen goes black. After a couple of seconds i am outside the application. But i dont get any dialog box saying that the app has stopped responding.

Comment: I have the same issue on Galaxy Ace. Maybe there is a bug in the last api?

Comment: were you able to find a solution for this? I am getting the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue using Tesseract 3.0.19 in native lib. Updating tess-data to version 3.02 helped me.